# c# asp.net "The server tag is not well formed"

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am creating a asp.net website in which i want to show the crystal report on the button click,i am having an error in my Default.aspx that "Error Creating Control-asp:Button The server tag is not well formed"

complete code is:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<%@ Register assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" namespace="CrystalDecisions.Web" tagprefix="CR" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Show Report"OnClick="Button1_Click" />

        <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" AutoDataBind="true" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

any help will be appreciated!

Comment: add a space before OnClick

Comment: @MethodMan No, you would only use `CodeBehind` with Web Application Projects. You use `CodeFile` with Web Site Projects.

Comment: @mason good catch I thought the OP was doing a web application I'll remove the comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Show Report"OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

should be

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Show Report" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the following

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Show Report"OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

to this

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Show Report" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```